# How to find duplicate values in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

How can we find and remove duplicate values along with their keys from a dictionary.

Example:

```
f = {1:4, 1:3, 4:4, 9:4, 5:7}
```

Output:

```
f = f = {1:3, 5:7}
```

As you can see all the keys with they duplicate value 4 have been removed...

Also is there a way to track how many items have been removed... in the above case 3 items have been removed.

Comment: I don't know where to start... i have searched lot.. but all the answers i got don't I cant connect with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Just iterate through `f.values()` and for each value iterate through again to see if there are any duplicates, then delete them. Although this would be sort of inefficient (`O(n^2)`)

Comment: It's not clear that your resulting dictionary would have `1:3` in it, because `1:4` and `1:3` share the same key so one of them will not exist, and depending on the input order it might be `1:3`.

Comment: @SethMMorton ... I am looking for the duplicate "values"....

Comment: @user3029969: But a dict doesn't allow duplicate keys, so you can't actually build a dict with both `1:3` and `1:4`. One of them will be removed.

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 .. how would I iterate a second time .. i cannot comprehend the coding in that..

Comment: I understand that, I'm just saying that it's impossible to have both `1:4` and `1:3` in a dictionary simultaneously, so one of `1:4` or `1:3` will be missing.  You can't have a duplicate value if python removed the entry because of duplicate keys.

Comment: ahh I see what u mean. +1

Comment: @user3029969 use loop like `for item in f.values(): ...` and then inside that loop, you nest the exact same loop (`for item2 in f.values()`), and this time, you could say, `if item2 == item1: ...` and delete the duplicate. However, you'd have to make sure that you don't remove an element because `item1` and `item2` are the same thing... you could count the duplicates and `if duplicates > 1:` remove the value. Of course, this is far easier with the built-in `collections`, as @user2357112 suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Count the values:

```
import collections
value_occurrences = collections.Counter(f.values())
```

then filter out the ones that appear more than once:

```
filtered_dict = {key: value for key, value in f.items()
                 if value_occurences[value] == 1}
```

To find how many were removed, just subtract the new dict's size from the old.

Comment: @user3029969: `import collections` first.

Comment: just to understand... key: value for key, value in f.items()... what does this line do

Comment: @user3029969: It's a dict comprehension. For every key-value pair in the original dict, if one occurence of the value was found when we counted them, that key-value pair is included in the new dict.

Answer (score 1):

to track how many items have been removed you can either just create a variable = 0 , and then += the variable by 1 for each time that it removes something

or

you could just measure the len(f) before you do this, and then measure the len(f) after you run your code, and see what the difference is between the two, and you got how many items have been removed

Comment: ahh yes that is an interesting and easy way of figuring out how many items have been removed... thank you with that help !

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
list1=[]
f = {1:4, 1:3, 4:4, 9:4, 5:7}
for value in f.values():
        if value not in list1:
                list1.append(value)
for key in f.keys():
        if key in list1:
                del f[key]
return f
```

the output will be

```
{1: 3, 5: 7, 9: 4}
```